# What is the minimum size in pixels for a viewable image

Tags: digital

I am developing an application that checks if image uploaded by a user is explicit or not.However it makes no sense to check images that are too small to be viewable(e.g 1x1 image).What image size do you suggest to be the minimum ?

**Edit**:
The image can then be viewed by people through their monitor or mobile phones

Comment: "explicit"[ly]  what?  What in the world are you trying to filter out?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft nude pics...

Comment: yeah, I was kinda afraid you'd say that.  Give it up. Now.  Are you going to censor The Birth of Venus?  or Napalm Girl?   Why do you think Google, which has about 35 000 people smarter than you  or me, still uses humans to classify images?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about selecting a probable lower limit to image size to optimize the processing requirements for software being developed by the questioner, rather than about the art, science, tools, or product of photography.

Answer (score 3):

Poor question.  There is no One Minimum size image, any minimum depends on the specific goal for how the image will be used (which you did not mention).

For printing, we usually want an image size to be 250 to 300 pixels per inch of print paper.   To print 10 inches at 300 dpi needs 3000 pixels of image dimension.

For video screen viewing, if the image size is say 600x400 pixels, then we see size 600x400 pixels. Screens are different sizes too, but you have to determine how large you want to see the image.  For HDTV, the screen size is normally 1920x1080 or 1280x720 pixels.  Cell phones are much smaller.  If the image is larger than the screen (both dimensioned in pixels), then most image viewing software will resample it smaller, and show a copy that will fit on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you the minimum area an image must occupy to be viable, I can tell you the standard regarding the size of the image elements. The photographic image is comprised of tiny image elements. If the image is to be assessed as “sharp”, these elements must be so tiny that they appear as points of light with no disenable dimension.

The basis of this is: If a friend hold up a coin and recedes from you, at some distance, the coin will cease to be perceived as a disk, it becomes a point. A disc will appear as a point when viewed by a person with 20/20 vision, in good light, at 1/3000 its diameter. In other words a coin 10mm in diameter appears as a point when viewed from 30,000mm = 30 meters (about 100 feet).

This value is too stringent for photographic purposes because we view images under lower light bigness conditions and the inherent contrast of photo images. The benchmark set is 3.4 minutes of arc which is a disc with a diameter of 1/1000 of viewing distance. This works out to 1/50 of an inch (0.5mm) viewed from 20 inches (500mm).

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, this is a poor question.

If you accept a favicon as an image for example, thoose are 16x16px.

### Historical sizes

But probably for practical and historical reasons, I would accept a **320x240px** image. That was the first "true" color resolution images back in the vga days. So you are not using just one random number.

I had a phone with that resolution and it was decent enough to show some pictures of the family.

If it is still too small, jump to **640x480px**

### Declared px on smartphones

Another option is to use a declared image size for smartphones, like **640x360px**, which is a 16:9 proportion. an image of this size will look decent enough on a smartphone. It is also a standard resolution for youtube videos with low bandwidth.

### Some resolution used on big companies

Youtube also uses a **426x240px** resolution or **256x144px** (which I think nobody uses).

### A 35 mm film proportion

If you are talking about photos, a well known proportion is 1:1.5 which was the proportion on a 35mm film.

So how about **300x200**

### Or a random number

300x300? Some online stores have photos that size.

Comment: Might as well mention avatar sizes for many of the big social sites. Facebook: 180×180. LinkedIn: 100×60. Instagram: 110×110. Twitter: 200×200. Pinterest: 165×165. Tumblr: 128×128. Google+: 120×120. Source: http://makeawebsitehub.com/social-media-image-sizes-cheat-sheet/